# Is it OK to manually pass a service instance into an object as a parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

If I use a service to encapsulate a collection of objects (common pattern for a data model), then is it a good design practice to pass the service instance to each of the objects in the collection?

I don't see a downside to this, since the service would only generate new objects as needed to store data, so there's not much advantage of 'tree shaking' here, and trying to make Angular inject it just seems like it would be more trouble than it's worth.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Service is a broad category encompassing any value, function, or feature that an app needs. A service is typically a class with a narrow, well-defined purpose. It should do something specific and do it well.

Angular distinguishes components from services to increase modularity and reusability. By separating a component's view-related functionality from other kinds of processing, you can make your component classes lean and efficient.

Ideally, a component's job is to enable the user experience and nothing more. A component should present properties and methods for data binding, in order to mediate between the view (rendered by the template) and the application logic (which often includes some notion of a model).

A component can delegate certain tasks to services, such as fetching data from the server, validating user input, or logging directly to the console. By defining such processing tasks in an injectable service class, you make those tasks available to any component. You can also make your app more adaptable by injecting different providers of the same kind of service, as appropriate in different circumstances.

Angular doesn't enforce these principles. Angular does help you follow these principles by making it easy to factor your application logic into services and make those services available to components through dependency injection.

Comment: I think I wasn't specific enough. I have created objects within one of my components. These objects need access to a service that is injected to the component. It appears that I can pass the service reference into the child objects as a parameter and this will give them access to the data that is stored in the service. It doesn't appear that this would cause any problems, since these objects are only created by the component, so even though I'm manually passing in the service, this only happens when the component is instantiated and the service is injected.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it my way and I really like how it's working now. I'm going to keep going with this direction. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you might be missing something.

A generally accepted design goal is "loose coupling". The ability to swap in a different implementation is a major reason for using injection.

Even if you're never going to swap in a different implementation of the service, providing it via injection makes it much easer to test. If you use injection, you can easily inject a mock service from a test, so that you are truly unit testing just the component.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line: Creating custom classes from an Angular component or service is just using Typescript in exactly the way it was intended.

*However, you will need to manually inject any services into each child object which you instantiate or else pass in the parent class's instance.*

In most cases, this won't be a problem from a performance perspective, since you will only be instantiating the child objects in cases where you have already instantiated the parent object.